# Using pynids on multiple pcaps

Tags: python, tcp, libnids

I am trying to parse multiple pcap files using the pynids library, but can get to parse only the 1st file. I saw that there was a function `nids_unregister_tcp` in libnids, will that help? I can't find that function in pynids though.

```
import nids


def handle_tcp_stream(tcp):
    print "In handle_tcp_stream"


def extract(pcap_file):
    nids.param("tcp_workarounds", 1)
    nids.param("pcap_filter", "tcp")         # bpf restrict to TCP only, note
    nids.param("scan_num_hosts", 0)          # disable portscan detection
    nids.chksum_ctl([('0.0.0.0/0', False)])  # disable checksumming

    nids.param("filename", pcap_file)
    nids.init()
    nids.register_tcp(handle_tcp_stream)

    try:
        nids.run()
    except Exception, e:
        print "Exception ", pcap_file + " ", e


def main():
    extract("a.pcap")
    print "Done"
    extract("a.pcap")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the output:

```
In handle_tcp_stream
In handle_tcp_stream
In handle_tcp_stream
In handle_tcp_stream
Done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding is written incorrectly it seems.

The Perl counterpart had also had this issue in the past: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=51107

Basically it can be summed up by:

> ...libnids cleans up and removes its callback once run() is
>   finished.

The error seems to be similar in here https://github.com/MITRECND/pynids/blob/master/nidsmodule.c#L533

I may be mistaken, but the `else` there makes it miss the actual registration when an `FP` was defined earlier. That `else` body should always be executed. So a quick fix is:

https://github.com/soulseekah/pynids/commit/8d420e88dbdc340f309db9db7c3b9c2508b1cb80

I'm a bit rusty on my Python API, but I think that `PyObject_Del` should be `Py_DECREF` instead. Although it works with deletion as well.

Watch https://github.com/MITRECND/pynids/pull/2 for more developments, I'm sure they'll figure out a more correct way to fix this. Meanwhile, what I did should work fine for the time being.

Too bad there aren't any unit tests to see if all is fine.

Comment: Thank you for working on it. For some reason, the quick fix doesn't seem to work on the 0.6.1 version available here:  https://oberheide.org/pynids/ But, the code on your github works fine.

Comment: @Phani, I tested the patch on both and both worked fine. Did you patch the `ndismodule.c` file and then run `python setup.py install` on it? Try removing the library from the lib path completely and reinstalling, should work.